# Seeking jQuery demo of sort and reorder like iPhone icons

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to duplicate the drag and reorder action of the icons on the iPhone screen.

I want to rearrange divs on a page basically. Like in flickr when you organize your images... you drag one and others make room for it. The gap where you removed it from closes up. I want to do the same thing with divs that contain data.

I did find one page here that offers some insight... but their demo doesn't even work. So the search continues.

I'm new at jQuery, but am getting there. If I could locate a demo of this solution I could work with it.

UPDATE... Meh... it is starting to look like I'll just use Sortables and just allow vertical sorting. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't do what you want but might point you in the right direction.

[Quicksand](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/)

Comment: Thanks Nalum. I did see that... they have some really nice looking stuff. I wish I had a need for that functionality. That would be cool to implement. Hmm... maybe I DO have a use for that too...

But it doesn't get me to my reorder items on my page thing.

Thanks for posting your reply!

Comment: The jQuery UI Sortables have a grid view which might be what you want though it doesn't animate. http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#display-grid